# Is it possible to match URLs before the question mark with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

We want to check if a URL matches mail.google.com or mail.yahoo.com (also a subdomain of them is accepted) but not a URL which contains this string after a question mark.

```
var possibleURLs = /(mail\.google\.com\/|mail\.yahoo\.com\/)/gi;
var url;
// assign a value to var url.
if (url.split("?")[0].match(possibleURLs) !== null) {
    // Do something...
}
```

But is it possible to match the url without "`.split("?")[0]`"? Can the regular expression contain the question mark? (any character can come before the matched string, except question marks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
var possibleURLs = /^[^\?]*(mail\.google\.com\/|mail\.yahoo\.com\/)/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using look ahead can be

```
^(?!\?mail\.(google|yahoo)\.com).*$
```

[**Regex Example Link**](https://regex101.com/r/nY3vG4/1)